# What happen when unused windings of double ratio current transformer left short?

Tags: current-transformer

I know that unused windings of double ratio currnet transformer should be left open.
I understand the reason and mechanism.

What happen if they are shorted.

I think, current of each tap ouput will be the same as their specification.
But, total current of winding will be sum of each tap output current.
So, winding can be overheated.

Is that right?

Comment: Please provide details, such as part number, current in your transformer, etc.

Comment: double ratio current transformer means that like 50/100/5A CT. 2nd winding has center tap. we have to select one tap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With its primary energised and secondary left open-circuit, a CT would suffer insulation failure caused by a very high voltage induced in its secondary.

With its primary energised and secondary short-circuited, no damage would be caused by the rated secondary current (5A) flowing through the short.

Likewise, with a dual-ratio CT.

[image]

Either with its 50A tap or 100A tap short-circuited, no damage would be caused by the rated secondary current (5A) flowing through the short.

A meter connected at the other tap would register a low erroneous reading.

> I think, current of each tap output will be the same as their specification.

With a dual-ratio CT, only one tap is to be used, based on the primary current range.

Only 5A would flow through either of them.

Comment: I'm trying to think this true intuitively. I always consider CTs as complimentary to VTs. VTs hate short circuits and love open circuits. I can tap off anywhere on the VT and leave the other taps open-circuit. CTs love short circuits and hate open circuits. If my complimentary model holds true then why don't we short out the unused tap? If we connect the meter between 0 and 50 will the CT not try to push current between the 50 and 100 taps? I need to think about this some more.

Comment: @Transistor  .  In Industry, a voltage transformer is referred to as a PT, potential transformer. Not objecting to your use of VT, just leaving the industrial version for others to note.

Comment: @Transistor, In a current transformer, the secondary current is decided by its turns ratio as well as its primary current (Is = Ip * [Np / Ns]).  Its primary current is decided solely by the external load and is not influenced by its secondary current.

Comment: @vu2nan, I don't think your second sentence can be correct. If the secondary circuit is consuming power then it *has* to affect the primary circuit - otherwise we've got free energy. See my question https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/544583/primary-voltage-drop-in-current-transformer. (I'm still thinking about that one and haven't accepted an answer yet although I've given some upvotes.)

Comment: @vu2nan transistor is correct here. There is a back emf induced in the primary of a ct. The induced emf in the primary is related to the induced emf in the secondary by the turns ratio. The induced emf in the secondary is affected by the burden resistance on the secondary. For small burden resistances, that emf is proportional to the burden resistance.

Comment: @Transistor & Maths Keeps Me Busy, I fully agree with you. With a 1:20 turns ratio, a 0.2 Ω ammeter burden would reflect as (0.2 / 20²) = 0.0005 Ω on the primary side leading to a primary voltage drop of (100 * 0.0005) = 0.5 V.

Comment: @vu2nan I think you are off by a zero. If 5 amps is flowing through a secondary burden of .2 ohms, there will be 1 volt through the burden. A 1:20 turns ratio gives 0.05 volts induced in primary.

Comment: @Math Keeps Me Busy, Thank you for pinpointing the typo and my complex reasoning!